# WARN TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2) in linux EC2 and Heroku servers

Tags: ruby, linux, heroku, amazon-ec2, webrick

```
[2013-01-29 09:17:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-01-29 09:17:50] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12) [i386-linux]
[2013-01-29 09:17:50] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2013-01-29 09:17:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4107 port=8080
```

When I run the file attached below in linux I get the error described. I tried all possible command and strategies online to listen to processes (including rogue) and kill them. I did this in lots of ports. No luck.

As soon as I run the script in Mac OS and it works. Nevertheless I have to mount it on a server and clients have to communicate with it. It happens on every instance of amazon ec2 and on heroku. I have seen this error one too many times and spend many hours trying to fix it. I configured the security group of ec2 instances and still did not work. I am beyond desperate. At this point I have to think that the problem must be WEBrick itself or something in my code.

```
    require 'webrick'
    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'

    $own_address = 8080


    class AuctionInfo
        # The representation is a hash mapping item names to [highest_bidder, highest_bid, end_time]
        def initialize
            @data = {}
        end
        def new_item(item, endTime)
            @data[item] = ["UNKNOWN", 0, endTime]
        end
        def bid(item, bid, client)
            if @data.has_key?(item)
                endTime = @data[item][2]
                if @data[item][1].to_i < bid.to_i and Time.new.to_i < endTime.to_i
                    @data[item] = [client, bid, endTime]
                end
            end
        end
        def get_status(item)
            if @data.has_key?(item)
                return @data[item][0]
            end
        end
        def winner(item)
            if @data.has_key?(item)
                if @data[item][2].to_i + 1 <= Time.new.to_i
                    return @data[item][0]
                else return "UNKNOWN"
                end
            end
        end
        def reset
            @data = {}
        end
        def has_item(item)
            return @data.has_key?(item)
        end
        def get_data
            return {}.replace(@data) 
        end
    end

class StartAuctionServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end

    def do_POST(request, response)
        if request.query['name'] and request.query['end_time']
            @data.new_item(request.query['name'], request.query['end_time'].to_i)
        end
        response.status = 200
    end
    alias_method :do_GET, :do_POST
end

class BidServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end

    def do_POST(request, response)
        if request.query['name'] and request.query['client'] and request.query['bid']
            @data.bid(request.query['name'], request.query['bid'].to_i, request.query['client'])
        end
        response.status = 200
    end
    alias_method :do_GET, :do_POST
end

class StatusServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end

    def do_GET(request, response)

        if request.query['name']
            response.body = @data.get_status(request.query['name'])
        end
        response.status = 200
    end
    alias_method :do_POST, :do_GET
end

class WinnerServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end

    def do_GET(request, response)
        if request.query['name']
            response.body = @data.winner(request.query['name'])
        end
        response.status = 200
    end
    alias_method :do_POST, :do_GET
end

class ResetServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end
    def do_POST(request, response)
        @data.reset
        response.status = 200
    end
    alias_method :do_GET, :do_POST
end

class RandomServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
    def initialize(server, data)
        @data = data
    end
    def do_GET(request, response)
        response.status = 200
        response.body = @data.get_data.to_s
    end
    alias_method :do_POST, :do_GET
end




data = AuctionInfo.new
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => $own_address)
server.mount '/start_auction', StartAuctionServlet, data
server.mount '/bid', BidServlet, data
server.mount '/status', StatusServlet, data
server.mount '/winner', WinnerServlet, data
server.mount '/rst', ResetServlet, data
server.mount '/', RandomServlet, data
trap("INT") { server.shutdown }
server.start
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked whether the linux server is running apache, tomcat, trinidad or any other web server?  Odds are one of them is already running on port 8080 on the server.

lsof is a useful command.  Try `lsof | grep 8080` and see whether anything shows up

Comment: `$ lsof -wni tcp:8080` may be more helpful here to find what is using that port.